# How to specify a default function argument with a template parameter type T

Tags: c++, templates, default-value, default-arguments

Is it possible to define the default value for variables of a template function in C++?

Something like below:

```
template<class T> T sum(T a, T b, T c=????)
{
     return a + b + c;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
template<class T> T sum(T a, T b, T c=T())
{
     return a + b + c;
}
```

You can also put in T(5) if you are expecting an integral type and want the default value to be 5.

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on the assumptions that you can do about the type.

```
template <typename T> T sum( T a, T b, T c = T() ) { return a+b+c; }
template <typename T> T sum2( T a, T b, T c = T(5) ) { return a+b+c; }
```

The first case, it only assumes that `T` is default constructible. For POD types that is value inititalization (IIRC) and is basically `0`, so `sum( 5, 7 )` will call `sum( 5, 7, 0 )`.

In the second case you require that the type can be constructed from an integer. For integral types, `sum( 5, 7 )` will call `sum( 5, 7, int(5) )` which is equivalent to `sum( 5, 7, 5 )`.

Comment: The default arguments are instantiated only if they are used. Which means one can put any crazy thing into them that wouldn't be compatible with `T` at all, which would be fine as long as one passes an explicit argument.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can define a default value.

```
template <class T> 
T constructThird()
{
    return T(1);
}

template <class T> 
T test(T a, 
       T b, 
       T c = constructThird<T>())
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

Unfortunately constructThird cannot take a and b as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there just needs to be a constructor for `T` from whatever value you put there. Given the code you show, I assume you'd probably want that argument to be `0`. If you want more than one argument to the constructor, you could put `T(arg1, arg2, arg3)` as the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

However you should at least have an idea about what T could be or it's useless.

You can't set the default value of template parameters for functions, i.e. this is forbidden:

```
template<typename T=int> void f(T a, T b);
```

Comment: Update - C++11 permits this.