# Default argument in function template C++

Tags: c++, templates

Just to be sure, from what I've read and tried, I can't put a default argument in a function template correct?  I've picked that much up both from my compiler AND from what other's have responded with...  I'm asking because I'm a newb and some of the more technical responses are hard to understand.  Is there a work around for this?  I'm trying to create a findmax function that uses a default relational operator but with the option to overload...ie:

```
template <typename Type, typename Compare = std::less<Type> >
Type FindMax(std:vector<Type> &vec, Compare comp = Compare()) {
    return *std::max_element(...
}
```

I suppose I could make a class for this but it seems like a lot of work when all I really want is one function...  Thanks!

I should add another question as well about something that I've seen before:

What does this function tempate do, specifically, what is the (cmpFn)...) default argument doing?

```
template <typename ElemType>
  ElemType FindMax(Vector<ElemType> &v, int (cmpFn)(ElemType, ElemType) = OperatorCmp)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[C++ template function default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301362/c-template-function-default-value)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of things to say:

1. What you defined is a *function template*, not a *class template*. Since you are using a **default template parameter**

   `typename Compare = std::less<Type>`

   I presume you are already using C++11, because for all I know function templates did not allow default template parameters in the previous versions of the standard.
2. On the other hand, **default arguments** of template parameters like this

   `Compare comp = Compare()`

   were possible in the previous version of the standard, too. Your statement that default arguments are not possible for templated parameters is wrong (or perhaps it actually referred to what I called *default template parameters* above).
3. The **compiler error messages** that you receive must be due to some other problem. Perhaps the `Type` you end up using does not go well with `std::less`, or the `Compare` type you use does not implement the default constructor. In any case, the following program compiles on GCC 4.6.2 (note that I changed the `std::vector<> &` to `const std::vector<> &` because that seemed more right):

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Type, typename Compare = std::less<Type> >
Type FindMax(const std::vector<Type> &vec, Compare comp = Compare()) {
  return *std::max_element(vec.begin(),vec.end(),comp);
}

int main() {
  FindMax(std::vector<int>());
  return 0;
}
```

And indeed this requires the `-std=C++0x` option, but that is because the default template parameter, not the default argument.

**About the extra question related to `cmpFn`:**

That declares a *function parameter*, i.e. an argument that is itself a function. The declaration

```
int (cmpFn)(ElemType, ElemType)
```

means the local name of the function is `cmpFn`, its return type is `int`, and it takes two arguments, both of type `ElemType`. The idea is that the caller can pass a function (or a functor) that will then be used to compare the elements of the vector. E.g. if you define the default value of that argument `OperatorCmp` before the function declaration like this:

```
int OperatorCmp(int a, int b) {
  return (a<b?-1:(a>b?1:0));
}
```

the declaration becomes valid and you can use it to find the maximum value of a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Thanks.  That second part is what I was looking for only I didn't realize it...a function parameter.

Comment: Note: `cmpFn` cannot be used with `std::max_element` because it expects a boolean result (similar to `<`), not a ternary result.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that in C++11. As of C++03 you can easily work around it by creating two overloads with different number of arguments and forwarding from one to the other.

```
template <typename Type>
Type findMax( std::vector<Type> const & v ) {
   return findMax( v, std::less<Type>() );
}
```

Alternatively you can use the standard algorithms and avoid having to write your own.