# Function with default parameter as template type

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am trying to use a function with a default argument as a function pointer template parameter:

```
template <void (*F)()>
class A {};

void foo1(int a = 0) {}
void foo2() {}

int main() 
{
    //A<foo1> a1;   <-- doesn't work
    A<foo2> a2;
}
```

The compiler error is:

> main.cpp:7:7: error: could not convert template argument ‘foo1’ to ‘void (*)()’

Is there specific syntax for this to work?  Or a specific language limitation?  Otherwise, the alternative is to have two separate functions instead of a default parameter:

```
void foo1(int a) {}
void foo1() { foo1(0); }
```

**Update**
I understand that the signatures are different, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work conveniently without needing to modify all the functions with default parameters?

Comment: Uncomment that line and it does not compile in ideone.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You forgot to uncomment the line that fails.

Comment: @JaredC Ah, copy-paste errors again! Thanks!

Comment: Uncomment the line, guys ;) The error here is pretty simple: default parameters are filled at call time -- there's still only one instance of the function, and its signature is with all the parameters: you can't take a `(*)()` to a `(*)(int)` function.

Comment: @JaredC Despite `foo1`'s parameter having a default value, the function signature is still `void(int)`, and that cannot be converted to `void(*)()`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Are you kidding? You didn't [uncomment the critical code](http://ideone.com/Hh2ak6)!

Comment: @Cory I figured as much.  Any way to 'trick' the compiler into doing what I need?  Or a more generic way to support this without having to modify all foo1s?

Comment: Default parameter does not change the signature of the function..

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[C++ template function default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301362/c-template-function-default-value)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section 8.3.6 of the C++ standard,

> If an expression is specified in a parameter declaration this expression is used as a default argument. Default arguments will be used in calls where trailing arguments are missing.

Since `A<foo1>` is *not* a call of the function, default arguments are ignored. In fact, they are ignored in all contexts except the calls of the function, for example

```
typedef void (*FFF)();
FFF x = foo1;
```

will not compile, and produce the same message that you get when trying to use `foo1` as a template parameter:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(int)’ to ‘void (*)()’
```

This makes sense, because evaluating default arguments is a separate step in the invocation:

> 8.3.6.9: Default arguments will be evaluated each time the function is called.

The presence of default arguments does not alter the signature of your function. For example, you cannot use a single-argument function with a default argument to override a no-argument virtual member function.

Comment: Is there a way to template the class so that F can have arbitrary parameters?  Then I could rely on the call site to fail if F() fails.

Comment: @JaredC Other than the variadic functions (similar to `printf`) I don't think there is a good way to accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: variadic templates are fine.  I should change the question to c++11.

Comment: @JaredC I meant the old variadic functions, not templates (i.e. something like `foo(char *,...)` and `va_start`/`va_arg`/`va_end` inside).

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `foo1` is `void(int)`, not `void()`. This is why it isn't convertible to `void(*)()`.

You are confusing default arguments with overloading.

Answer (score 2):

Default argument values are not part of the function type. You can't use `foo1` as a function taking no arguments, because it does take one argument. The argument gets filled in for you if you don't mention it, but it's still there.

Your workaround involving a dispatching function sounds like a good solution. It could even be templated if you need it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that a function pointer has signature of the function with all default parameters expanded and function pointers cannot convert to a function pointer with a different signature. Finding this in the standard is a different matter, though...

I think the relevant clause from the standard is 8.3.5 [dcl.fct] paragraph 6:

> ... The return type, the parameter-type-list, the ref-qualifier, and the cv-qualifier-seq, but not the default arguments (8.3.6) or the exception specification (15.4), are part of the function type. [ Note: Function types are checked during the assignments and initializations of pointers to functions, references to functions, and pointers to member functions. —end note ]

Note that *default arguments* are the guys of the form `= value` according to 8.3.6 [dcl.fct.default] paragraph 1:

> If an initializer-clause is specified in a parameter-declaration this initializer-clause is used as a default argument. ...

Answer (score 1):

It won't compile because `foo1` has signature:

```
void foo1(int a);
```

which you're trying to stick into a pointer to:

```
void F()
```

The function signatures don't match. The fact that `foo1` has a default parameter doesn't change the function's signature (it still can take in an `int`).

### A More Generic Solution

I'd say forget about the templates, they're only limiting you here.

Personally, the way I solve the callback problem is using **function objects** with **argument binding**. It can be done using the [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html) library, and binding default arguments with [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html) (or [`std::bind1st`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind1st/) and `std::bind2nd`).

These boost libraries are also built-in to the new C++11 standard, as [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

It's well worth taking a look at this, as it let's you do some very nice things, like providing default arguments to functions, or use class member functions as callbacks.

The sites I've linked to all have lots of example code, and the boost links have tutorials.