# C++(11) Default arguments for functions as template parameters, or as function pointers

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, default

Basically, I want a function pointer to be able to be called with default arguments.  Take a look at the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int function(int arg1 = 23)
    {
        printf("function called, arg1: %d\n", arg1);
        return arg1 * 3;
    }

template<typename Fn> int func(Fn f)
{
    int v = 3;
    f(); //error here 'error: too few arguments to function'
    f(23); //this compiles just fine
    return v;
}


int main() {
    func(&function);
    printf("test\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way (trickery or otherwise) to be able to call a function with default arguments from a function pointer (or a template argument) without specifying the argument explicitly?

Comment: I would just call `func(function);` in your `main`...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425618/function-with-default-parameter-as-template-type

Answer (score 2):

Yes There is a Good way. Function Object. I highly recommend you to see this link.

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/course-reader/Ch13_Functors.pdf

Answer (score 1):

With [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). It returns a function object that calls the function with arguments that you passed to bind expression:

```
auto f = std::bind(&function, 23);
func(f);
```

Comment: Problem is, you'd have to know the value of the default argument and explicitly specify it in the call to bind().  I'm trying to write a signal class that holds a function pointer and calls this function upon invocation, and can take any arbitrary function as an argument to connect(), so in that case I wouldn't know the default argument.

Comment: Somehow, you need to get your hands on the value of the defaulted parameter. It's not possible to do this with a function pointer alone.