# C++ function template using default parameters

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template <typename Object, typename Comparator>
const Object &findMax(const vector<Object> &arr,
         const Comparator &isLessThan = less<Object>())
{
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (isLessThan(arr[maxIndex], arr[i])) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return arr[maxIndex];
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> arr(3);
    arr[0] = "ZED";
    arr[1] = "alli";
    arr[2] = "crocode";
//...
    cout << findMax(arr) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with g++, it gives the following error:

```
test4.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test4.cpp:48:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘findMax(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’
test4.cpp:48:24: note: candidate is:
test4.cpp:10:15: note: template<class Object, class Comparator> const Object& findMax(const std::vector<Object>&, const Comparator&)
```

Comment: I can't figure out your error, but you could consider `std::max_element`

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[C++ template function default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301362/c-template-function-default-value)*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Template parameters cannot be deduced from default arguments. C++11, [temp.deduct.type]§5:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - ...
> - A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done.
> - ...

You can get around this using overloading:

```
template <typename Object, typename Comparator>
const Object &findMax(const vector<Object> &arr, const Comparator &isLessThan)
{
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (isLessThan(arr[maxIndex], arr[i])) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return arr[maxIndex];
}

template <typename Object>
const Object &findMax(const vector<Object> &arr)
{
    return findMax(arr, std::less<Object>());
}
```

Comment: when 'findMax' is a function member of a class template it works well.why?

Comment: @tangwenqiang You mean it's a member function template? Or is it a plain member function and `Comparator` is a template parameter of the enclosing class template?

Comment: 1 #include <iostream>
  2 using namespace std;
  3 template <typename Object>
  4 //class A {
  5 //    public:
  6         Object retself(const Object &initVal = Object())
  7         {
  8             return initVal;
  9         }
 10 //};
 11 int main()
 12 {
 13     //A<int> test;
 14     cout << retself() << endl;
 15     return 0;
 16 }
run it(will get error); delete the '//', replace line 14 with 'cout << test.retself() << endl (will be ok); I want to konw why?

Comment: @tangwenqiang Because when it's a non-template member function of a class template, the template parameter comes from the enclosing class template and does not have to be deduced. So no problem there.

Answer (score 5):

Default the template argument and the function argument. Use `max_element` (actually, don't even define this function, just use `max_element` wherever you would have called this).

```
template <typename Object, typename Comparator = std::less<Object>>
const Object &findMax(const vector<Object> &arr, Comparator comp = Comparator())
{
    return *std::max_element(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), comp);
}
```

Disclaimer: not tested, and must have C++11

Answer (score 4):

Using default template parameters in C++11, your function could be written this way:

```
template <typename Object, typename Comparator = std::less<Object> >
const Object &findMax(const vector<Object> &arr, const Comparator isLessThan = Comparator())
{
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (isLessThan(arr[maxIndex], arr[i])) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return arr[maxIndex];
}
```

Note the usage of default template parameter `typename Comparator = std::less<Object>`.