# C++ default parameter in template not allowed?

Tags: c++

In my C++ code, I wrote like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Pred>
inline const T BestOfTwo(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, Pred p = std::less<T>())
{
    return p(lhs, rhs) ? lhs : rhs;
}
```

But this didn't work when I called **BestOfTwo(3, 5)**. The compiler told me that no instance of overload matched. So now I have to write it like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Pred = std::less<T> >
inline const T BestOfTwo(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, Pred p = Pred())
{
    return p(lhs, rhs) ? lhs : rhs;
}
```

And this worked with no error when I called **BestOfTwo(3, 5)**. But I think the previous style is more convenient and I didn't figure out where it went wrong. What are some suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[C++ template function default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301362/c-template-function-default-value)*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only the second version is correct (if you don't want to specify the `Pred` parameter manually), but only since C++11. There is already an answer from Angew that clarify why the first version is incorrect, without specification of the `Pred` parameter.

If you cannot use C++11 you should write two overloads (one with `Pred` and one without, that use `std::less`), since default template parameters for function templates are explicitly forbidden in C++98.

```
template<typename T, typename Pred>
inline const T BestOfTwo(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, Pred p = Pred())
{
   //
}

template<typename T>
inline const T BestOfTwo(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
   return BestOfTwo<T, std::less<T> >(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The first version would work if you specified the template arguments explicitly:

```
BestOfTwo<int, std::less<int>>(3, 5)
```

The reason is that default function arguments cannot be used to deduce the type for a template parameter.